# How to create this gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

Could you tell me how to create this radial gradient ?

[image: gradient]

[image: half gradient]

My current CSS:

```
background: radial-gradient(closest-corner, #b0ff9f 40%,
            #9dfa89 40%, #9dfa89 50%, #7af16a 50%, #7af16a 60%,
            #60ea54 60%, #60ea54 70%, #00b4ff 70%, #00b4ff 100%);
```

Comment: @Mr Lister, yes, i don't know how to do this with css

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show the code?

Comment: @MrLister, I figured it out. now i have this css code: background: radial-gradient(closest-corner, #b0ff9f 40%, #9dfa89 40%, #9dfa89 50%, #7af16a 50%, #7af16a 60%, #60ea54 60%, #60ea54 70%, #00b4ff 70%, #00b4ff 100%);

Comment: But it is not what i want to get. i need something like this https://ibb.co/mTi8L6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Rather than using a fixed-size keyword, you will need to fine tune the radius and position. The rest of what you had is OK.

```css
body {margin:0}
div {background: radial-gradient(ellipse 80% 100% at center bottom,
     #b0ff9f 40%, #9dfa89 40%, #9dfa89 50%, #7af16a 50%, #7af16a 60%,
     #60ea54 60%, #60ea54 70%, #00b4ff 70%, #00b4ff 100%);}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px"></div>
```